# Function in url parameter in jQuery Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run a function to generate the `url` used in a jQuery ajax POST request, but it seems the `url` parameter can only be a string... Here is the code, note the `function` in the `url` parameter of the ajax call:

```
//chained code upstairs...
.bind("create.jstree", function (e, data) {
    $.ajax({
        //"/project/<%= locals.project.handle %>/mkdir/<%=locals.filepath%>",
        //"http://127.0.0.1/project/datanotes/mkdir/lolada/lolada_subdir",
        type : "POST",
        url :   function(data){
            var url = "<%= locals.request.db.baseURI + "/project/" + locals.project.handle + "/mkdir" %>";
            if(data.rslt.obj.attr("id") != null){
                url = url + "/" + data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
            }
            return url;
        },
        data : {
            "title" : data.rslt.name,
            "type" : data.rslt.obj.attr("rel")
        },
        success: function (r) {
            if(r.status) {
                $(data.rslt.obj).attr("id", "node_" + r.id);
            }
            else {
                $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
            }
        },
        failure : function (r) {
            $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
        }
    });
})
```

The url parameter is interpreted as a string and not evaluated, as the debug log is the following:

```
GET /project/datanotes/browse/children 200 369ms - 2b
POST /project/function%20(data)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20url%20=%20%22http://127.0.0.1:3000/project/datanotes/mkdir%22;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(data.rslt.obj.attr(%22id%22)%20!=%20null)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%20=%20url%20+%20%22/%22%20+%20data.rslt.obj.attr(%22id%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20url;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D 404 5ms
```

Can you help me circunvent the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you can do this or not (what you're trying), but why not run the function right before the AJAX call, assign it to a variable, then use that?

Comment: Exactly, that is the best solution, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing the function, not executing it and passing the result. You could use an immediately invoked function:

```
url: (function () {
    var url = "<%= locals.request.db.baseURI + " / project / " + locals.project.handle + " / mkdir " %>";

    if (data.rslt.obj.attr("id") != null) {
        url = url + "/" + data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
    }

    return url;
})(),
```

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yS6rn/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain the immediately invoked function. Works well and is something I did not know :-)

Comment: Although I would never consider using this technique to solve this specific circumstance (as it adds unneeded complexity) +1 for coolness :)

Comment: I would tend to agree.. in this case, it's probably not necessary. But it offers a way to make the asker's attempted solution work, and IIFE's are a good think to know about.

Answer (score 4):

You were expecting a function to be evaluated when only a string was required. Why overcomplicate it? Just calculate the URL before the AJAX call (but still inside the binding function).

```
//chained code upstairs...
.bind("create.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var url = "<%= locals.request.db.baseURI + " / project / " + locals.project.handle + " / mkdir " %>";

    if (data.rslt.obj.attr("id") != null) {
        url = url + "/" + data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
    }

    $.ajax({
        //"/project/<%= locals.project.handle %>/mkdir/<%=locals.filepath%>",
        //"http://127.0.0.1/project/datanotes/mkdir/lolada/lolada_subdir",
        type: "POST",

        url: url,

        data: {
            "title": data.rslt.name,
                "type": data.rslt.obj.attr("rel")
        },
        success: function (r) {
            if (r.status) {
                $(data.rslt.obj).attr("id", "node_" + r.id);
            } else {
                $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
            }
        },
        failure: function (r) {
            $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: You are right, simple is always better and I will take your approach; however, the immediately invoked function was a new thing for me, and thus I will accept the other answer as it taught me something new and it solves the problem also. I will upvote nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: That's cool... I was impressed by it too. All functions in Javascript are apparently just strings... Opens up some interesting possibilities for self-modifying code! :)